# Original array values are modified

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```js
let a = {x: "x"};
let b = {b: "b"};

let versions = [a, b];
let copyOfVersions = Array.from(versions);
let test = ["test"];
    
copyOfVersions[0].versions = Array.from(test);

console.log(versions[0].versions);
```

How come that `versions` table values have changed too?

Thanks!

Comment: Array.from does not perform deep copy

Comment: Why do you think that `Array.from` _copies the objects_ in the array?

Comment: I used `Array.from` when I found this post  [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript). But even if doesn't perform a copy, it creates a new instance. So I don't understand why the original value changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: Quoting your link on accepted answer : "slice copies object references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you created a new instance of an array by using *Array.from*. So *versions* and *copyOfVersions* are two different objects, but they both contain list of references to the same objects. So that means when you say *copyOfVersions[0]* and *versions[0]* you are basically accessing the same object *a*. Then when you use *.versions* you are adding a new field. In the end, only object *a* has been changed and that's what you see as print out.

Answer (score 1):

`a` and `b` are references to the objects `{x: "x"}` and `{b: "b"}` respectively.

When you create a new array, those references are copied to the new array but the **referenced objects are NOT copied**, it's still the original objects that are referenced.

`copyOfVersions[0]` gets the referenced object, the same object referenced by `versions[0]`, and then you create the property `versions` on that object. Since the object itself was never copied, you're modifying the original object.